# C# Template Forms Get panel in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that I have created that contains a panel - panel1.
I have then created a template form that inherits the first form.

How can I add something to the panel that I inherited from my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the panel's `Modifiers` to `Protected` in the property grid.

Answer (score 1):

Make panel1 visible using **protected** keyword so it will be visible in your inherited class.